# CSS Warnings about Cross Browser CSS Attributes

Tags: css, warnings, suppress-warnings

I often get warnings from my CSS files about invalid CSS Properties when I'm using a series of browser specific properties as follows:

```
-moz-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
-o-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
-webkit-animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
animation: spin 2s infinite linear;
```

In this case Chrome whines as follows: `Invalid CSS property value: spin 2s infinite linear`. I know it's ignorable because:

a) Chrome uses webkit
  b) the `.icon-spin` class works just fine.

I dislike warnings...ignoring them is almost always wrong.  Any chance there's a way to either

a) resolve the warning by changing code like that
  or
  b) supress css warnings in this sort of context?

Also note that I've seen this in other contexts, where the non-vendor-prefixed css property is still non-compliant.

Comment: What is generating the warnings? I never got warnings about "invalid" css?

Comment: Sorry, realized that after I posted, was mid-edit when you commented.

Comment: Try putting the one without vendor prefixes on top and the webkit version right below it.

Comment: Isn't that...non-traditional?

Comment: You can always use **JS** to detect which browser are you using and add only that browsers _prefix_.

Comment: Since the non prefixed version is going to be the new standard its best to put it on top anyways. All the other ones are just fallbacks, so no reason to treat them otherwise.

Comment: @Severin, feel like answering with that explanatoin..makes sense t ome.

Comment: @ChristopherPfohl Btw, see [prefixpree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

Comment: @Severin: That's not how it works. If you put the unprefixed version on top it will be useless until the prefixed version stops being supported entirely because it'll just override the unprefixed one. In CSS, fallback rules are usually specified earlier, not later.